# Pasar arreglos bidimensionales como parametros en c++ | Programacion dinamica - Viaje mas barato por el rio

Tags: c++, array

Estoy haciendo el problema del viaje mas barato por el rio. Pero pasa
que siempre he tenido problemas para pasar como parametro un arreglo
bidimensional, he probado con

```
int menorCandidato(int origen, int destino,int n, int T[][10], int &C)
```

y

```
int menorCandidato(int origen, int destino,int n, int T[][10], int C[][4])
```

y otros si no lo que podria hacer es poner valores fijos. Pero me gustaria implementar para que el usuario pudiera asignar los valores para el array T que es la tabla de tarifas.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int embarcaderos(int origen, int destino, int T[][10]);
    int menorCandidato(int origen, int destino,int n,int T[][10], int &C);
    int minimo(int a, int b);
    int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Numero de embarcaderos: ";cin>>n;
    int T[n][n]={ {0,3,4,10},{3,0,1,3},{4,1,0,1},{10,3,2,0} };
    //imprimir T
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<endl;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            cout<<T[i][j]<<" ";
        }
    }
    //cout<<"Solucion: "<<embarcaderos(1,5,T);

}

int embarcaderos(int origen, int destino, int T[][10],int n){
    int C[n][n];
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<n;j++){
            C[i][j]=menorCandidato(i,j,n,T,C);
        }
    }
    return C[n][n];
}
int menorCandidato(int origen, int destino,int n, int T[][10], int &C){
    int temp;
    temp=100;
    for(int i=origen+1;i<n;i++){
        temp=min(temp,T[origen][i]+C[i][destino]);
    }
    return temp;
}
int min(int a, int b){
    if(a<=b)
    return a;
    if(b<a)
    return b;
}
```

Comment: 26 36 C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\ViajeRio.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[n]' to 'int (*)[4]' for argument '5' to 'int menorCandidato(int, int, int, int (*)[10], int (*)[4])'   Cuando compilo habiendo puesto la 2da opcion que mostre me sale este error

Answer (score 2):

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int T[n][n];
```

Querido amigo, la variable `T` del ejemplo, sacado de tu propio código, es un VLA (Variable Length Array), y **no** está soportado por el estándar de C++. Hay compiladores que lo soportan pero no es una solución portable (es decir, puede que funcione en tu equipo pero que seas incapaz de compilarlo en clase o al revés).

Además, en el caso de funcionar, los VLA son delicados ya que, como has podido comprobar, dan problemas al llamar a funciones y el motivo es que en C++, las llamadas a funciones quedan establecidas en tiempo de compilación. Si no se conoce el tamaño del array en tiempo de compilación, dificilmente podrá el compilador determinar si el array es compatible con una función determinada.

En cualquier caso no hay que negar que, aunque funcionase, el código tiene sus riesgos. Por ejemplo... ¿Qué pasaría en el siguiente ejemplo si el usuario introduce un `2`?

```
int n;
cout<<"Numero de embarcaderos: ";cin>>n;
int T[n][n]={ {0,3,4,10},{3,0,1,3},{4,1,0,1},{10,3,2,0} };
```

¿Qúe pasaría con los valores que *no entran* en el array? Y si introduce un 6, ¿Habrá valores sin inicializar en la matriz?

Posibles soluciones:

**Usa memoria dinámica**

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;

int ** T = new int*[n];
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
  T[i] = new int[n];
```

De esta forma los parámetros de las funciones serán punteros dobles, sin más precauciones.

```
int menorCandidato(int origen, int destino,int n, int** T, int ** C);
```

**Usa memoria dinámica (v2)**

En este caso, en vez de dos reservas de memoria vamos a realizar únicamente una. Esto obligará a programar nosotros el cálculo de las filas/columnas.

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;

int * T = new int[n*n];
for( int i=0; i<n*n; i++ )
  T[i] = new int[n];

// Acceso a una posición del array
int fila, columna;
T[fila*n + columna] = 123;
```

Para simplicar su uso podemos encapsular los datos en una clase:

```
class Matriz
{
  int filas_;
  int columnas_;
  int * datos_;

public:

  Matriz(int filas, int columnas)
    : filas_(filas)
    , columnas_(columnas)
    , datos_(new int[filas*columnas])
  { }

  ~Matriz()
  { delete[] datos_; }

  int& Get(int fila, int columna)
  { return datos_[fila*columnas_ + columa]; }
};


int n;
std::cin >> n;
Matriz T(n, n);

T.get(fila, columna) = 123;
std::cout << T.get(fila, columna);
```

El diseño de la clase se podría complicar ligeramente para conseguir un uso más natural, este ejemplo es únicamente ilustrativo.

**Uso de contenedores**

Otra posiblidad pasa por hacer uso de contenedores de la STL:

```
int n;
std::cint >> n;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> T(n, std::vector<int>(n, 0));

T[filas][columnas] = 123;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Siempre he tenido problemas para pasar como parámetro un arreglo bidimensional.

En C++, el tipo de un arreglo es: `tipo[tamaño]`. Así que para pasar como parámetro un arreglo, puedes pasarlo como referencia:

```
void funcion(int (&arreglo)[100]);
```

La función `funcion` aceptará sólo arreglos de `100` enteros (`int`):

```
int diez[10];
int cien[100];

funcion(diez); // ¡Error! no se puede convertir int[10] en int[100]
funcion(cien); // ¡Correcto!
```

Personalmente, creo que la notación `tipo (&nombre)[tamaño]` es terrible, por lo que suelo aconsejar usar un alias, o un alias plantilla:

```
using cien_enteros = int[100];

template <int tamanyo>
using arreglo_enteros = int[tamanyo];

void funcion(cien_enteros &arreglo);
void funcion(arreglo_enteros<10> &arreglo);

int cien[100];
int diez[10];
int tres[3];

funcion(diez); // Correcto, llama a void funcion(cien_enteros &)
funcion(diez); // Correcto, llama a void funcion(arreglo_enteros<10> &)
funcion(tres); // ¡Error!
```

Todo esto funciona igual para arreglos de más dimensiones:

```
funcion(int (&arreglo2d)[10][10]);
```

La función anterior sólo aceptará arreglos de enteros de `10` filas y `10` columnas. Con alias:

```
using a10x10 = int[10][10];

template <int filas, int columnas>
using matriz = int[filas][columnas];

funcion(a10x10 &a);         // Recibe arreglos de 10 filas y 10 columnas
funcion(matriz<12, 34> &m); // Recibe arreglos de 12 filas y 34 columnas
```

---

Todo lo anterior es lo que puedes hacer para pasar arreglos **de tamaño conocido** como parámetros. Pero **NO** es lo que estás necesitando en tu código, ya que tú estás trabajando con arreglos de tamaño desconocido. Para los casos que buscas, la respuesta de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/277680/2742) es excelente.